# Stuck on "grub>" prompt when dual-booting Ubuntu

Tags: install, grub

On the dual boot option screen I choose Ubuntu and only get:

```
grub>
```

I want to get into Ubuntu and start learning it a bit but am stuck. What would be the best way to fix my problem?

Comment: Can you change your title to more closely resemble your question? It should definitely have something about the grub prompt.

Answer (score 3):

Next time I need to pay attention to where I install Ubuntu. If it is on an external media, like in this case, I either need to leave the drive plugged in, although I dont believe you can readily boot an OS via USB, or install Ubuntu locally.

Comment: "I dont believe you can readily boot an OS via USB" - have u tried?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so I'm answering here.  You can most definitely single-, dual- or multiple-boot OSs from a USB drive*. What do you mean "install Ubuntu locally?

*As long as the BIOS supports booting from USB of course. All modern BIOSes support this. If you have a BIOS which does not, boot off the Plop Boot CD which then provides USB boot support.

Comment: Locally I meant on the current hard drive I was using. I was able to fix the issue though. I appreciate the comments.

Comment: @Cross Your post was converted into a comment. To reply to an answer or comment in the future, use the `add comment` button below the answer. This is a [questions and answers site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/about), not a forum where posts appear in chronological order. Please delete this answer and post its contents as a comment where it belongs. You can also now accept your actual answer (click the checkmark next to it).